# JList not being set to invisible worked before

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I have been converting a project that I did for c# into java and I am having trouble implementing this last part. The project is a fantasy football tracker and the issues is with letting the user go in and change the active roster and the master roster.

So far there is no issue with making changes to either or the issue is that I want to combine functionality so that when they are done with one roster they can make changes to the other roster if they wish.

The weird thing is that I have it to work one way so that the user can change there active roster and then switch to there master roster with no issue;however it does not work the other way the user can change there master roster.

When they say they want to change the other roster the setVisible dose not work on the JList that contains the users master roster.

```
//This is the method that sets up the users active roster
public void activeRosterLook()
{
   //scroll holds the users master roster
  // this is the issue it will work in one instance but not the other
  // so when this method is called the first time it works
  // but when it is called a second time or called after 
  //the user changes the master roster
 // it decides not to become invisible
scroll.setVisible(false);

//bar holds the users active roster 
bar.setVisible(true);

// master is a button that when clicked starts the master roster change
master.setVisible(false);

//actuve is a button that when clicked starts the active roster change
active.setVisible(false);

// prompt is a label that gives directions on the frame 
prompt.setVisible(false); 

}

// this if checks to see that the Done button which triggers this change is clicked
if(Done.equals(e.getSource()))
{
    // this if makes sure the master button was clicked 
    if(ismaster)
    {
       // changing the booleans up so that my frame runs properly 
       isactive = true;
       ismaster = false;

       // this if makes sure that the active roster is not empty
       // I have this here because when they go change the active roster it
      // fills both rosters and when they go change the master it only fills the master              
      // roster 
       if(activePlayers[0] == null)
       {
           try
           {
             this method accesses the file that has the active roster data  
              loadActiveRoster();
           }
           catch(IOException ioe)
           {
              //This catch will never run the way I have the files set up
           }
       }
       // this method is called the issue is with the actual look method 
       activeRosterLook();
    }
    // this runs when active is clicked
   if(isactive)
  {
      // doing the same thing swapping the booleans 
      ismaster = true
      isactive = false

      // and this method will change the frame to the master roster changes
      // the only difference is that this method works and the changes occure
      masterRosterLook();
  }

}
else
{
   // this also works if the user does not want to change anything else sends
   // them back to the hub or the form that launches these frames
   StartUpForm hub = new StartUpForm(true);
    dispose();
}

 }
```

I was wondering if anyone would have an idea as to why the setVisible will work on one 
jList and not the other? Also why the setVisible will work on this particular roster in
one situation and not the other?

Comment: Consider using a CardLayout, that's what it's designed for

Comment: I need the power of null layout for what i am doing I looked into the card layout. I am moving things around more than just what cardLayout has to offer.

Comment: `null` layout is an illusion brought about a lack of experience with layout managers - in 14 years of professional Swing development, I've never used a `null` layout for any kind of user based forms.

Comment: I am not opposed to changing the layout from null to something else maybe border because I need to display the two JLists side by side for the user to change that roster and what I saw of card layout the cards lay on top of one anther not side by side. Also changing the layout may or may not solve this issue with setVisible. I also do not have them in a JPanel because of my inexperience with GUI would this help with the set visible function?

Comment: Remember, you can use compounding layouts.  You don't need to be stuck with one.